# Combine map-reduce output from different folders into single folder

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have map-reduce output on grid split across several folders. The format of each file is same. Each folder has a bunch of files: 
Example: /folderpath/folder1/part-r-00001 to /folderpath/folder1/part-r-00100 
...  /folderpath/foldern/part-r-00001 to /folderpath/foldern/part-r-00100

What is the easiest way to combine the contents together, i.e aggregate the files into single folder (which i want to use later)
/folderpath/merged/part-r-0000* ... /folderpath/merged/part-r-000n

I can think of pig script which reads output from each path and does union of relations read, then dumps them.

Any other option/ command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pig would be very easy:

```
data = LOAD '/folderpath/folder*' USING PigStorage('\n');
STORE data INTO '/newfolderpath';
```

Alternatively you can use the hadoop shell's `getmerge` function, but this will turn everything into a single file on your local disk.

If the files aren't too big, this would be an easy way to turn it into a single file on HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /folderpath/folder* | hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal - /newfolderpath/file
```

Comment: Yes, even I thought the pig script earlier (as mentioned in ques). I will go with it. Thanks!

Comment: I did see it in the question, but note that it can be even simpler than you describe -- there is no need to read the inputs separately and do a `UNION`.  Just `LOAD` all at once and then `STORE`.

Comment: Oh yes. That is much simpler! No need of UNION. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly just write a short bash script using hadoop fs commands.

```
hadoop fs -mv /source1/somefolder/.* /destination/somefolder
hadoop fs -mv /source2/somefolder/.* /destination/somefolder
```

put a line in for each folder you need moved.

Comment: This won't work because the files in different directories have the same name.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus just specify the absolute path. For instance if you have folder one say the following:  `put /user/all/folders/back/to/root/source1/somefolder/.*` Do the same for the others. It is imposibble for two folders to have the same absolute path, so that should solve the problem.

Comment: Right, but the files themselves have the same name, so they can't be put into the same folder without renaming them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I guess the pig script solves the renaming problem so I went with that!